# Lawn tractor won't start

Tags: engine, electrical, lawnmower, toro

Not sure if this is the right stack exchange forum to post this in or not, hoping it is...

I have a Toro lawn tractor which is having issues starting. I have been using it fine for the last few weeks since I purchased it second hand and it has always started easily. Then today I went to start it and all I hear from under the dash is a buzzing type sound coming from the starter relay. I have taken the battery out which is a 12v battery and put it on the charger, the charger says it is fully charged even though when I put my multimeter on it it only shows 10v. When I try shorting out the poles on the starter relay bypassing it and manually trying to start the starter motor nothing happens other than a few sparks between the poles. I don't know if the battery needs replacing, needs a different charger attached, or if I need to take it into a repair joint to have the starter relay replaced. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is the right SE for this question. Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is most likely the battery ... well, I'll even go a little stronger than that ... you battery is *definitely* an issue.

A fully charged 12v battery should be around 13.1-13.5vdc when fully charged. As it gets older, the "full" voltage decreases and it will no longer provide enough juice to start the engine.

I would test this theory by placing a known good 12v battery in it's place to start the engine. If it starts just fine, you know this is the issue. I'm pretty sure replacing it with a new one will solve your issue.